# Change event not firing after deselecting a radio button

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if any one of the three radio buttons having the same class is checked or not, and depending on the result, I want to hide or show another radio button.

```
var MyThreeRadioButtons = $(".radioButtonsIWantToCheck");
MyThreeRadioButtons.change(function () {
    if (MyThreeRadioButtons.is(":checked")) {
        $(".buttonIwantToHide:radio").hide();
    } else {
        $(".buttonIwantToHide:radio").show();
    }
});
```

When I added console.log statements to see if the code is invoked, I noticed that the code doesn't run when I uncheck any of the radio buttons.

Comment: This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery).

Comment: Radio button or Checkbox ?

Comment: @Swati Radio button

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons can't be uchecked with interaction (in a group one of them is ever checked) and if you uncheck them via code, the change event is not fired

Comment: I'm not unchecking them via code. I want to make a decision based on the checked or unchecked state of the radio button.

Comment: As written before, _'radio buttons can't be unchecked with [human] interaction'_: in a group, one of them is ever checked (except in the initial state) and then `is(":checked")` is ever true.
For this purpose you can instead use checkboxes (as @Swati supposed).
Otherwise you should explain better your needings